# Cant figure out how to customize the featureType "landscape"

Tags: google-maps-api-3, customization

I'd like to customize the featureType "landscape" so that the underlying relief (mountains and valleys) remains untouched, but the landscape cover, which is mostly green, is removed.

Specifically, I am interested in Swiss map. (see [Swiss map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z2vJp.jpg)). Now, if I set

```
  {
     featuretype: "landscape.natural.terrain",
     stylers: [
      { visibility: "off" }
     ] 
  }
```

**everything** related to "landscape.natural" disappear. The same thing happens if I set

```
  {
     featuretype: "landscape.natural.landcover",
     stylers: [
      { visibility: "off" }
     ] 
  }
```

The list of available featureTypes doesn't provide any other landscape type to affect the landcover more specifically, but I am not an expert, so I am wondering whether what I'd like to do is even possible, and if so how.

Thank you very much in advance for your support,
Franco

Answer (score 0):

It is because you set the visibility of all related to the `featureType` to `off`.

> Styled maps allow you to customize the presentation of the standard Google base maps, changing the visual display of such elements as roads, parks, and built-up areas.
>
> Styled maps use two concepts to apply colors and changes to a map:
>
> - *Map features* are the geographic elements that can be targeted on the map. These include roads, parks, bodies of water, and more, as well as their labels.
> - *Stylers* are color and visibility properties that can be applied to map features. They define the display color through a combination of hue, color, and lightness/gamma values.

The one you use

> *visibility (on, off, or simplified)* indicates whether and how the element appears on the map. A simplified visibility removes some style features from the affected features; roads, for example, are simplified into thinner lines without outlines, while parks lose their label text but retain the label icon.

Familiarize yourself to [*MapTypeStyle object specification*](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#StyledMapTypeOptions)

- List of [`FeatureType`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MapTypeStyleFeatureType)
- [`ElementType`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MapTypeStyleElementType)
- [`Styler`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MapTypeStyler)

To learn more on styling the maps go to [Customizing Google Maps: Styling the Base Map](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorials/styling-the-base-map)

Hope this helps